# Date format in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

I am using the following function to Convert a String variable to a Date. Subtract a day from it and convert the date back to a String. The code goes as follows

```
Dim edate As String
Dim expenddt As Date

edate = txtenddt.Text
expenddt = Date.ParseExact(edate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
expenddt = expenddt.AddDays(-1)

Dim asd As String = expenddt.ToString
```

If `edate` has a value **29/12/2011** than the value in `expenddt` gets changed to a different format and the value in `expenddt` comes to **12/29/2011** and later after subtracting a day `expenddt` is **12/28/2011** and than when i convert it back to a String i get the value in `asd` as **"12/28/2012 12:00:00 AM"**

I have changed the date format on my system to `d/M/yyyy` in Regional And Language Option in Control Panel but i still get a different format in `expenddt`

Can anyone explain me why this is happening? How can i keep the format of the date in dd/mm/yyyy e.g 29/12/2011 and after 
Subtracting a day it should remain **28/12/2011** and not **12/29/2011**

Comment: I can't explain why (it should be using the format set via Control Panel), but why don't you just specify the format when you call ToString?

Comment: @andygjp . That i never thaught of.Thank you so much. Actually im new to vb, i know how we do it in C# .Can you please tell me how to Specify a format? is it .ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Date.ToString()` to convert date to string with `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

```
Dim asd As String = expenddt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
Dim dateString As String = "Mon 16 Jun 8:30 AM 2008"
Dim format As String = "ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy"
Dim dateTime__1 As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

hope this may helpful....